# Configure Pentaho data Integration to connect to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, database-connection, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have configured Oracle VirtualBox with DB, user and populated a small DB.
In the same machine I've installed Pentaho Data-Integration(Spoon), the JDBC driver and I'm trying to create a connection to Oracle DB but without success.
This is where I'm typing the credentials/data:

**Host Name**: localhost

**Database Name**: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))

**Port Number**: 1521

**User Name**: SYSTEM

**Password**: oracle

[image]
**This is the error message:**

```
Error connecting to database [oraConn12c] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
IO Error: NL Exception was generated TNS-04605: Invalid syntax error: Unexpected char or LITERAL "(" before or at  ( DESCRIPTION =


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
IO Error: NL Exception was generated TNS-04605: Invalid syntax error: Unexpected char or LITERAL "(" before or at  ( DESCRIPTION =


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:459)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:357)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:328)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:318)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at 
.......
... more  .....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: NL Exception was generated TNS-04605: Invalid syntax error: Unexpected char or LITERAL "(" before or at  ( DESCRIPTION =
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:569)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: NL Exception was generated TNS-04605: Invalid syntax error: Unexpected char or LITERAL "(" before or at  ( DESCRIPTION =
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAddrTree(AddrResolution.java:733)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:493)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 58 more

Hostname       : localhost
Port           : 1521
Database name  : (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))
```

How can I configure it in order to connect Pentaho/Spoon to the Oracle DB?
The oracle DB seems to be working fine, I've also tried with other users/databases that I created, but the result is the same.

Comment: I think you should only have the name of the database in that field. The protocol, host and port are already defined.

Comment: Try removing the port number. I think you don't need the PORT number

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this same issue by removing 'Host Name' and 'Port Number' details from the connection window. Leaving only the 'DB Name' string.

Comment: Me too. That way I succeed the connection test but then when I use the configured data source I get: "IO Error: NL Exception was generated". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Could solve it that way for the client tool, but not for the carte server.

I fixed it with an JNDI connection.

put this in your pdi\simple-jdni\jdbc.properties

```
mydb/type=javax.sql.DataSource
mydb/driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
mydb/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=myport)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservicename)))
mydb/user=myuser
mydb/password=mypassword
```

and this connection in your repositories.xml:

```
<connection>
<name>JNDI</name>
<server>myserver</server>
<type>ORACLE</type>
<access>JNDI</access>
<database>mydb</database>
<port>myport</port>
<username>myuser</username>
<password>mypassword</password>
<servername/>
<data_tablespace/>
<index_tablespace/>
<attributes>
  <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_LOWERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_UPPERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>IS_CLUSTERED</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>PORT_NUMBER</code><attribute>myport</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>QUOTE_ALL_FIELDS</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
  <attribute><code>USE_POOLING</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding

```
(FAILOVER_MODE=(type=select)(method=basic)(retries=20)(delay=3))))
```

to the end of the string solved it for us.